# notepad++ insert value in single(certain) line(not use String)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I was wondering how to put some new value(or new line) after exactly 5th line of text in NotePad++. My solution(combinations of others):

**Search**: `\A(.*.)\r\n(.*.)\r\n(.*.)\r\n(.*.)`
**Change**: `\1\r\n\2\r\n\3\r\n\4\r\n\5STRING`

*Input*:

```
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
```

*Output*:

```
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
STRING
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
12345,67890,12345,67890
```

Is there any another(more readable) option to do this ?

Comment: Use menu => **Search** => **Goto...** . Select line and 5, then just start typing.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a limiting quantifier `{min,max}`/`{exact_num}` with a grouping construct that will match lines, and you also need to match the *whole document* with the `\A` and `\z` anchors **for the pattern replacement to work in both `Replace` and `Find in Files`**:

```
\A((?:.*\R){4})([\s\S]*)\z
```

and replace with `$1STRING\r\n$2`. Just put the cursor at the start of the document and hit `Replace` twice.

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of document
- `((?:.*\R){4})` - (Group 1 later referenced to with `$1` from the replacement pattern) Match 4 sequences of 0+ chars other than a newline (`.*`) up to the end of line and the linebreak (`\R`, add `+` after it if there can be multiple line breaks, or `?` if there can be just 4 lines in the document, or `*` if there can be 0 or more line breaks)
- `([\s\S]*)` - (Group 2 later referenced to with `$2` backreference) matches 0+ any characters, including a newline up to
- `\z` - the very end of the document.

The replacement pattern contains the backreference `$1` that refers to Group 1, `STRING\r\n` (`STRING` with a CRLF linebreak) and a `$2` backreference.

Now, you can click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> and you will get the single replacement performed in your document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is that i want use it on group of files(with multiple lines) in 'find in files' by catalog and put new value exactly one time in exactly one place. So count on file should be: Count:1 matches(not 3 times when number of lines is 15). I have some problems with rebuild your pattern \A(?:.*\R){4}. Can you help ?

Comment: Do you mean the Find in files works as if you clicked Replace All button? I think you may use `\A((?:.*\R){4})([\s\S]*)\z` and replace with `$1STRING\r\n$2`